# Plotly bar chart - emphasise maximum value of each group

Tags: plotly, bar-chart, streamlit

I create plotly bar chart using the next line

```
fig = px.bar(df_to_print, x="bin_dist", y=metric, color='net_id',  barmode="group", text=metric, color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Vivid)
```

and got this chart (using Streamlit):
[image]

I want to bold the maximum value on each group, something like:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try the following code From the graph structure, I changed the color and thickness of its border since it is the second of a bar chart. `fig.data[1].marker = dict(line_color='black', line_width=2)`

Comment: This works but it will highlight the 2nd serious issue. In my case, I can get a different graph behaivor. Meaning the max value in each group may vary.